# Flask python json parsing

Tags: python, json, flask

Hello I am completely new to flask and python. I am using an API to geocode
and i get a json which is

```
"info": {
    "copyright": {
      "imageAltText": "\u00a9 2015 MapQuest, Inc.", 
      "imageUrl": "http://api.mqcdn.com/res/mqlogo.gif", 
      "text": "\u00a9 2015 MapQuest, Inc."
    }, 
    "messages": [], 
    "statuscode": 0
  }, 
  "options": {
    "ignoreLatLngInput": false, 
    "maxResults": -1, 
    "thumbMaps": true
  }, 
  "results": [
    {
      "locations": [
        {
          "adminArea1": "US", 
          "adminArea1Type": "Country", 
          "adminArea3": "", 
          "adminArea3Type": "", 
          "adminArea4": "", 
          "adminArea4Type": "County", 
          "adminArea5": "", 
          "adminArea5Type": "City", 
          "adminArea6": "", 
          "adminArea6Type": "Neighborhood", 
          "displayLatLng": {
            "lat": 33.663512, 
            "lng": -111.958849
          }, 
          "dragPoint": false, 
          "geocodeQuality": "ADDRESS", 
          "geocodeQualityCode": "L1AAA", 
          "latLng": {
            "lat": 33.663512, 
            "lng": -111.958849
          }, 
          "linkId": "25438895i35930428r65831359", 
          "mapUrl": "http://www.mapquestapi.com/staticmap/v4/getmap?key=&rand=1009123942", 
          "postalCode": "", 
          "sideOfStreet": "R", 
          "street": "", 
          "type": "s", 
          "unknownInput": ""
        }
      ], 
      "providedLocation": {
        "city": " ", 
        "postalCode": "", 
        "state": "", 
        "street": "E Blvd"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

RIght now i am doing this

```
data=json.loads(r)
return jsonify(data)
```

and this prints all the data as shown above. I need to get the latlng array from locations which is in results. I have tried
`data.get("results").get("locations")` and hundreds of combinations like that but i still cant get it to work. I basically need to store the lat and long in a session variable. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can use data as a `dict` of  `dict` and `list`.

Comment: that is probably above my level of comprehension of python dist and lists, this is my first time doing python. what would it be in terms of a c++ or c approach? thanks!

Comment: follow this [python types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you just have one location as in your example:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json

r = ...
data = json.loads(r)

latlng = data['results'][0]['locations'][0]['latLng']
latitude = latlng['lat']
longitude = latlng['lng']

print(latitude, longitude)  # 33.663512 -111.958849
```

Comment: this makes sense but when i try it says TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
Trying to remedy this

Comment: @user4992422, ah, I don't think you included all of the output :). Even with the output you did include, I made a small error. Fix your output and I'll fix the code. EDIT: Never mind, I found the error. Editing the answer now.

Comment: haha so syntax errors now but i get the error
ValueError: View function did not return a response
Any clue?

Comment: @user4992422, that sounds like something else, not related to this; something to do with Flask. You should ask a separate question for that :).

Comment: @user4992422, no problem :). Can you accept this then, so the question will be marked as answered?

Comment: @Cyphase you just corrected your answer after I posted my answer.

Comment: @salmanwahed, it appears I did, though I didn't see your answer before I went looking for it just now. I found the mistake on my own after OP gave me the error he was getting. I hope you don't think I plagiarized you! :)

Comment: That's ok. Normally you should explain your answer why it should work rather than just giving the code and if you make an edit that's already in an answer, you should mention about that answer also.

Comment: @salmanwahed, if I had gotten it from your answer, I would have. As I said, I didn't even see your answer until you commented here :).

Answer (score 2):

`data.get("results")`  will return a list type object. As `list` object does not have `get` attribute, you can not do `data.get("results").get("locations")`

According to the `json` you provided, you can do like this:

```
data.get('results')[0].get('locations') # also a list
```

This will give you the array. Now you can get the `lat` and `lng` like this:

```
data.get('results')[0].get('locations')[0].get('latLng').get('lat') # lat
data.get('results')[0].get('locations')[0].get('latLng').get('lng') # lng
```

Answer (score 0):

I summarize my comments as follows:

You can use data as a `dict` of  `dict` and `list`.

A quick ref to `dict` and `list`:

> A dictionary’s keys are almost arbitrary values.

```
get(key[, default])
```

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

[official docs about stdtypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)